# Cannot fix induced 0x7b error on XP

Tags: windows-xp, repair

I'm writing a tool that will automatically fix the STOP 0x7B error that occurs when windows cannot access the hard drive due to driver issues (usually). I've wrote a tool that does everything the [Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314082) says to do.

But it's not working.

I'm inducing the issue by changing the BIOS SATA controller to AHCI, then moving it to another computer and updating it's registry. When I move it back to the other computer, nothing new happens.

Can someone tell me what more I need to do?

Comment: Maybe more of a StackOverflow question?

Comment: No - stackoverflow is programming.

Comment: Nope, I've already wrote the program and it works fine. It does everything the knowledge base says it should. But that's where I'm stuck. The knowledge base article doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most likely because the list of registry entries in the KB article only includes the controllers already supported by a standard XP install. Some of the more recent machines I've had to set up need additional entries for Intel's iaStor driver (registry entries at http://polsy.org.uk/stuff/iastor.reg.txt though these are obviously not guaranteed to be the ones you'll need. Also needs the iaStor.sys driver file).

Basically you need to know ahead of time which registry entries (and files) the AHCI controller requires so you can add them in when the problem arises.

Comment: This sounds like it will work. I need to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the hard disk for errors? Almost all the 0x7b errors i found got solved by doing a hard disk repair (I used mostly HDD regenerator found on Hiren´s Boot CD, other times, using the Recovery Console from XP install CD and running a CHKDSK on the disk).

Comment: No the hard disk is fine. The problem is induced. Not from disk errors.